# Infectious disease outbreakes in Russia by region

Tags: data-request, medical, russia

Are there sources where I can find information about infectious disease (say, plague, hepatitis, polio) outbreakes in modern Russia? Typically, a disease outbreak is followed by a warning issued by public health regulators: are those kind of data archived and tallied? I'd prefer to have the data grouped by regions. A go-to resource at [FSSS](http://www.gks.ru/wps/wcm/connect/rosstat_main/rosstat/en/figures/health/) lists surprizingly little about public health.

Comment: You can try to find something in FSSS's «[ЦБСД](http://cbsd.gks.ru)»: see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYfOH.png). However, data is very incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many](http://globalhealthgovernance.org/blog/2017/12/1/how-to-find-data-on-infectious-disease-outbreaks) global infectious decease outbreaks databases.
For example, [Gideon](https://web.gideononline.com/web/epidemiology/#) (15-day free trial) provides data of this kind:

---

[image: Gideon. Hepatitis A in Russia]

---

There are also many sources of statistical information from Russian federal authorities (or their territorial bodies):

- *Rosstat* statistics (see [my comment](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/infectious-disease-outbreakes-in-russia-by-region/12262#comment14597_10713) above);
- *Minzdrav* annual reports ([an example](https://static-2.rosminzdrav.ru/system/attachments/attaches/000/026/606/original/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D0%B2_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A0%D0%A4_1.06.2015.docx?1434620518));
- *Rospotrebnadzor* annual reports ([an example](http://www.rospotrebnadzor.ru/upload/iblock/0b3/gosudarstvennyy-doklad-2016.pdf)).

Unfortunately, all these sources are rather unsuitable for your needs.